# PHP regex for matching ALL special characters, included accented characters

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a way to match all the possible special characters in a string.
I have a list of cities in the world and many of the names of those cities contain special characters and accented characters. So I am looking for a regular expression that will return TRUE for any kind of special characters.
All the ones I found only match some, but I need one for every possible special character out there, spaces at the begin of the string included.
Is this possible?

This is the one I found, but does not match all the different and possible characters I may encounter in the name of a city:

```
preg_match('/[#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]/', $string);
```

Comment: Define "special". What is "special" to you? Have you thought of doing it the other way around, defining a list of characters you deem "non-special" and checking if anything *except those* are in the string?

Comment: How about everything that is **not** "A-Za-z"?

Comment: How about using just `\W`?

Comment: its better to define what should not be matched, because there are many special characters plus accented

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need the UTF8 mode "#pattern#u": https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Then you can use the Unicode escape sequences: https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

So that preg_match("#\p{L}*#u", "København", $match) will match.

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode properties:

`\pL` stands for any letter

To match a city names, i'd do (I suppose `-` and space are valid characters) :

```
preg_match('/\s*[\pL-\s]/u', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just reverse your pattern... to match everything what is not "a-Z09-_" you would use

```
preg_match('/[^-_a-z0-9.]/iu', $string);
```

The ^ in the character class reverses it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I wanted to split nameparts which also contained special characters:

For example if you want to split a bunch of names containing:

`<lastname>,<forename(s)> <initial(s)> <suffix(es)>`

fornames and suffix are separated with (white)space(s)
initials are separated with a . and with maximum of 6 initials

you could use

```
$nameparts=preg_split("/(\w*),((?:\w+[\s\-]*)*)((?:\w\.){1,6})(?:\s*)(.*)/u",$displayname,null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
//first and last part are always empty
array_splice($naamdelen, 5, 1);
array_splice($naamdelen, 0, 1);
print_r($nameparts);
```

Input:
`Powers,Björn B.A. van der`
Output:
`Array ( [0] => Powers[1] => Björn [2] => B.A. [3] => van der)`

Tip: the regular expression looks like from outer space but [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to the rescue!